# Create a view with filters

Tags: android, view, filtering

Good morning, stackoverflow community, can someone help me create a view similar to the image attached, it is a project to perform a search and then refine the results, the screenshot is taken from the Mercado Libre application so they have A better idea of how I want to implement. Thank you in advance for your help.[image: , C]

Answer (score 0):

I am guiding myself on the next project in case anyone is interested
https://github.com/nhaarman/supertooltips

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a custom spinner for this, and there implement all the filters and get all those values through callback. I am providing a link  to implement the custom spinner [Custom Spinner](https://www.edureka.co/blog/custom-spinner-in-android)